# Android Wear Tile only works with TileUiClient

Tags: java, android-studio, wear-os, wear-os-tiles

I'm trying to write an Android Wear tile in Java. I finished my design using the TileUiClient.
Previewing the Tile in an Activity works fine, but as soon as I try to view the tile normally it doesn't show anything anymore. It just displays the Tile Name and Icon. When I try to do the same in Kotlin it works fine. Does anybody know why that could be?

What it should look like:

[image: Preview in Application]

What it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

Here's my Java code:

```
package com.example.wear.tiles;

import static androidx.wear.tiles.ColorBuilders.argb;
import static androidx.wear.tiles.DimensionBuilders.degrees;
import static androidx.wear.tiles.DimensionBuilders.dp;
import static androidx.wear.tiles.DimensionBuilders.expand;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.wear.tiles.ActionBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.DimensionBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.LayoutElementBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.ModifiersBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.RequestBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.ResourceBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.TileBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.TileService;
import androidx.wear.tiles.TimelineBuilders;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;


public class Tile extends TileService {
    private static final String RESOURCES_VERSION = "1";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<TileBuilders.Tile> onTileRequest(@NonNull RequestBuilders.TileRequest requestParams) {

        return Futures.immediateFuture(new TileBuilders.Tile.Builder()
                .setResourcesVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION)
                //.setFreshnessIntervalMillis(60*1000*5) // 60 minutes
                .setTimeline(new TimelineBuilders.Timeline.Builder()
                        .addTimelineEntry(new TimelineBuilders.TimelineEntry.Builder()
                            .setLayout(new LayoutElementBuilders.Layout.Builder()
                                    .setRoot(new LayoutElementBuilders.Text.Builder().setText("Test").setModifiers(new ModifiersBuilders.Modifiers.Builder().setSemantics(new ModifiersBuilders.Semantics.Builder().setContentDescription("lol").build()).build()
                                            ).build()
                                    ).build()
                            ).build()
                    ).build()
            ).build()
        );
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<ResourceBuilders.Resources> onResourcesRequest(@NonNull RequestBuilders.ResourcesRequest requestParams) {
        return Futures.immediateFuture(new ResourceBuilders.Resources.Builder()
                .setVersion("5")
                .build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found my mistake, I set two different Versions in **.setVersion("5")** in `onResourcesRequest()` and `onTileRequest()`. I initially changed them, because it seemed to solve an other problem(My pictures weren't rendered). **Always set the same version number.**